# Executing a POST request via Insomnia is always resulting in MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: rest, post, laravel-5.5

I need to build just the API of a specific function in this project, and for testing I'm using [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/). But when attempting to send the request, the application will throw a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`.

I've set up the following route:

```
Route::post('/backend/users/store', 'ClientUserController@insert')->name('cms.users.store');
```

In the `ClientUserController`, I configured the `insert` method to be allowed as a guest:

```
$this->middleware('auth', [ 'except' => [ 'insert' ] ]);
```

Then I just set up the URL in the software and tried sending a request, causing the exception to be thrown.

[image]

Comment: I try to send POST request with Basic Auth and JSON body. It always sent it as a GET request.
If you select PUT, it seems ok, but body stay empty.

Comment: I am having the same annoying problem! And it has WASTED lots of my time!!